# Access multiple cells within cell array

Tags: matlab

```
for i=1:30
    a{i}=rand(2,2);
end
a{[6 23]}=[] %get an error here
```

How do I access element 6 and 23 **efficiently**?

Comment: @Jack - That command would get "The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side."  There are two solutions depending on if the goal is to remove the cells or to assign empty arrays into them (answered below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign emptys array to the contents of those two cells, you can use the brackets (`[]`) and `deal`:

```
[a{[6 23]}]=deal([])
```

If instead you want to remove those two cells entirely, use parentheses:

```
a([6 23])=[]
```

The reason `a{[6 23]}=[]` gives an error is because accessing a cell array that way returns a comma-separated list of the cell contents.  In other words, doing `[a{[6 23]}]` is like doing `[a{6},a{23}]`.